# AngularJS slow to load unless in private browsing mode in Chrome?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

In angularjs, I make a request out to a service, get some data, show it in a div. I notice that when Google Chrome is in the default non-private browsing, it takes 30 seconds before the request is made whereas when I go to the same URL in private browsing mode, the response comes back in 3 seconds. Why is this? Is there something that private browsing mode does that allows angularjs to run faster? Is there some switch or some code I can add such that the default Google Chrome that may give it the faster load time? is it something to do with caching?

Note: The slowness/delay the $http GET request is executed only occurs on the initial load.

Comment: Private browsing mode in Chrome has the additional effect of disabling most extensions. Have you tried disabling some of your extensions and seeing if things run faster in non-private browsing?

Comment: Yes, disabling all extensions appears to have no effect on the "delay" that happens before making the initial $http request to pull in a resource.

Comment: Do you have JS console open and have `Disable cache (while DevTools is open)` enabled? It could slow the loading time because it starts to load everything. I've experienced this once and it's the only thing that pops to mind. But if this is the case, it's a huge red flag.

Also, try it in different browser where you have none or very little plugins.

Comment: I do not have the console open in either case. I would think that non-Private Browsing would be faster since it probably would cache as opposed to private browsing mode, which is loading super fast in comparison.

Comment: I have the same issue. @Rolando have you managed to come up with a solution or idea why this is happening?